Balcony door base frame chewed by a Rat/Mice
My balcony door base frame is chewed by a rat/mice (very small one) to make an entrance to the house. Mice is now gone, but left the scar. Shall I use wood filler to fill the gap as shown in red highlighted area? What about the weather strip part?


Could use Durham's Rock Hard Water Putty too.

Also How do I fix a door frame that my dog chewed?
